# Regex to match "Warm Regards"-type email signatures

Tags: regex

I am an absolute regex noob and have been banging my head against the wall trying to write a regex to remove email signatures from a string that look like this:

```
Hi There, this is an email.

Warm Regards,

Joe Bloggs
```

Thus far, I’ve tried variations on:

```
/^[\w |][R|r]egards,/
```

The regex should:

1. look at the beginning of the line (what I was aiming for with the `^`,
2. cover variations like “Warm Regards”, “Kind Regards”, “Best Regards”, and plain old “Regards” (which I was hoping to accomplish with the `[\w |]` to match any word or blank and the `[R|r]` to cover Regards/regards),
3. be OK with mixed case like “warm regards” or “Warm Regards”, and
4. only pickup lines that are `[word] Regards` or just `regards`, so that we don’t grab email body that has the word “regards” somewhere in it.

This seems elementary, but I just can’t nail it, and I seem to err on broadening my regex too much such that any line that contains “regards” gets picked up. I’m doing this in Node.js combined with the `string.search` function if that matters.

Comment: Do you want the signature to remain?

Comment: you forgot a quantifier (i.e. `+`) after `[\w |]`, like this it only matches one character: "X regards". I think your misconception is that "\w" means "a word". It is "a *word* character": usually this means numbers, letters, underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to fit all your requirements:

```
^(\w*\s)?[r|R]egards,?
```

Has to start on a new line, then can have any word followed by a space, and the word regards, or just the word regards, with the comma also being optional.

If you want to wipe out everything after the regards line as well you can add in `\s*.*`

```
^(\w*\s)?[r|R]egards,?\s*.*
```

Comment: This regexp matches (my regards) in "my regards to Tom" too because it does not care about line end.

Comment: Actually this matches `|egards` too. The vertical bar in the character class is superfluous, or actually just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to remove everything from the `Warm Regards` line on, this should do it

`^[^<]*?(?=(.*)[R|r]egards)`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regular expression

```
^\w* ?regards,?
```

with the case insensitive & global flag specified.

You can see the regular expression explanation and what it matches here: http://regex101.com/r/vR3zG5

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression that matches signatures defined in #1-#4 is following:

```
/^(\w+ +)?regards,? *$/im
```

How it works:

- "^" in the beginning means new line
- "(\w+ +)?" means optional segment that contains exactly one word followed by at least one space
- "regards" is just a simple match
- ",?" optional comma at the end
- " *" - the line may contain trailing spaces (it may be useful to put the same match after ^)
- "$" - end of line
- /.../i - means that the expression is case-insensitive
- /.../m - means that ^ and $ match at line breaks